# for loop only for a certain part of an equation in python

Tags: python

I would like to sum a function (in my case `f = np.exp(x))` inside of an equation. I'm not sure if I am right to think like that but I think I saw my teacher do something like this once. Any idea how that would work? Here is the code:

```
trc = (h2 / 2) * (f(x0) + (2 * (sum(f(i)) for i in xi)) + f(x8))
```

where `f(i)` is my equation evaluated for every `i in xi` (which is a list of float)

```
def f(x):
    return np.exp(x)

xi = [0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.825]
```

Comment: So just do `for i in xi: f(i)`.

Comment: if you make `xi`an `np.array` for consistency it would only be np.sum( f( xi ) )` that's it. No need to manually iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy allows calculation of element-wise exponential for an array. Thus you could simply do:

```
trc = (h2/2)*(f(x0) + 2*sum(f(xi)) + f(x8))
```

You could also keep what you have written and modify it as follows:

```
trc = (h2/2)*((f(x0)) + 2*sum([f(i) for i in xi]) + (f(x8)))
```